# How do I get the date in MM/DD/YYYY format in perl. I am using perl 5.8

Tags: perl

Hi I am trying to store the date in a variable $date. I will then use Excel::Writer::XLSX to print the date into a cell. I am using perl 5.8. I know a lot of the modules used for getting the date such as TimePiece were installed in later versions of perl.

Comment: Why would you use Perl 5.8 in 2019?

Answer (score 5):

```
use POSIX qw( strftime );

strftime('%m/%d/%Y', localtime)
```

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that [Time::Piece](https://perldoc.pl/Time::Piece) is only core since Perl 5.10. But you can install it from CPAN. You could then use its strftime method:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;
my $date = localtime->strftime('%m/%d/%Y');
```

Without it, you can use the built-in [localtime](https://perldoc.pl/functions/localtime) function, which also has a nicer wrapper [Time::localtime](https://perldoc.pl/Time::localtime) (even in 5.8). You just have to be careful because the values returned by POSIX localtime aren't exactly what you'd expect.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::localtime;
my $now = localtime;
my $date = sprintf '%02d/%02d/%04d', $now->mon + 1, $now->mday, $now->year + 1900;
```